# Efficient way to parse a datagram in Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp

Right now I am using a socket and a datagram packet. This program is for a LAN network and sends at least 30 packets a second at 500 bytes maximum.

this is how I am receiving my data

```
payload = new String(incomingPacket.getData(), incomingPacket.getOffset(), incomingPacket.getLength(), "UTF-8");
```

Currently I am using no offset and I parse one by one through each character. I use the first 2 characters right now to determine what type of message it is but that is subject to change, then I break down variables and seperate the data with an exclamation mark to tell me when the next variable begins. At the end I parse it and apply it to my program. Is there a faster way to break down and interpret datagram packets? Will there be a performance difference if I put the length of the variables in the offset. Maybe an example would be useful. Also I think my variables are too small to use StringBuilder so I use normal concatenation.

Comment: Is it too slow? (Only you can answer that question)

Comment: @immibis yes, it is too slow, now give me ways of doing it faster. I'm going to test out DataInputStream and ByteArrayInputStream and see how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about here is setting up your own protocol for communication. While I have this as the fourth part of my [socket tutorial](http://www.coding.ractoc.com/socket-programming-part-1) (I'm currently working on part 3, non-blocking sockets) I can explain some things here already.

There are several ways of setting up such a protocol, depending on your needs.
One way of doing it is having a byte in front of each piece of data declaring the size, in bytes. That way, you know the length of the byte array containing the next variable value. This makes it easy to read out whole variables in one go via the [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) method. This is a method I've used before. If the object being sent is always the same, this is all you need to do. Write the variables in a standardized order, add the size of the variable value and you're done.

If you have to send multiple types of objects throught the stream you might want to add a bit of meta data. This meta data can then be used to tell what kind of object is being sent and the order of the variables. This meta data can then be put in a header which you add before the actual message. Once again, the values in the header are preceded by the size byte.

In my [tutorial](http://www.coding.ractoc.com/socket-programming-part-1) I'll write up a complete code example.

Comment: Please don't. I've found several errors in your tutorial already. `System.arraycopy()` is a counsel of despair. I haven't used it this century.

Comment: Thanks for the finds in the tutorial, they should be fixed now where needed and explained in more detail where not. Above I'm just stating one way of doing things, nowhere am I stating it is the only or the best way. I've used this approach before with  much success though so I'd be interested in the problems you've run into.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. I didn't say anything about running into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `String` at all. Just process the underlying byte array directly: scan it for delimiters, counts, what have you. You can use a `DataInputStream` wrapped around a `ByteArrayInputStream` wrapped around the byte array if you want an API oriented to Java primitive datatypes.